# How are the Taylor series taken?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, numerical-methods, taylor-expansion

A lecture slide from numerical analysis shows how the taylor series is taken.

$$\frac{u_{i+1}-u_{i}}{h}=u_{i}^{\prime}+\frac{h}{2} u_{i}^{\prime \prime}+\frac{h^{2}}{6} u_{i}^{\prime \prime \prime}+\mathcal{O}\left(h^{3}\right)$$

I normally do not have trouble with the Taylor series, but I cannot see how one goes from the left hand side to the right hand side.

Due to covid-19 I cannot go to uni and ask my professor. Hopefully someone could provide me with the insight to solve this.

Ter

Comment: If you multiply both sides by $h$ and then add $u_i$ to both sides, does it look more familiar?

Comment: Write $u_{i+1} = u(x_i + h)$ and expand this by Taylor at $x_i$.